# Substring an absolute path based on inconsistently named folder

Tags: php, wordpress, require, absolute-path

## What I have:

I have a path for a `require_once` function that's created by **1)** finding the string position of a specific folder name and **2)** by using the said string position to `substring` the file path.

```
$url    = dirname( __FILE__ ); 
//e.g. /home/somesite/public_html/wp-content/themes/some-theme

$strpos = strpos( $url, 'wp-content' ); 
//e.g. 27

$base   = substr( $url, 0, $strpos );
//e.g. /home/somesite/public_html/

require_once( $base .'wp-load.php' );
```

## My problem:

Though the above code works, it assumes that the folder (`wp-content`) will always be named consistently. It won't be. There's instances where it could be renamed to infinite alternatives e.g. `assets`, `wpcontent`, `content`, `not-wp-content` etc. and thus, the created absolute path is incorrect and throws a fatal PHP error.

## My question:

Is it possible to create the necessary path without a consistent folder name?

*Note: Though the code is being used in a WordPress environment, the document itself (`style.php`) does not avail of WordPress API functions though it eventually calls `wp-load.php` using the created path so this is in effect, a pure PHP question.*

Comment: Well, what will the paths always have in common?

Comment: @msfoster The only commonality I see is the end of `dirname( __FILE__ );`, which would be `/themes/some-theme`. I'm presuming that `/public_html/` might not be a consistent path convention across all servers.

Comment: @msfoster Is there a of "wildcarding" the folder name that precedes `/themes/some-theme/` to `substring` the path at the end of the slash that precedes the "wildcarded" folder?

Comment: Ok, so you'll always have `somefolder/themes` in the path?

Comment: @msfoster Yes, that's correct.

Comment: How about using some sort of ABSPATH kind of variable or realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])  which would give the wordpress installation root folder and constructing the URL from that?

Comment: Ok, so you just need to remove the three last folders? That's it?

Comment: @msfoster Yes, that's correct,

Comment: If you just need to go three folders up, then using `../` three times will do.

Comment: @thanix `ABSPATH` won't work since it's proprietary to the WordPress API (see note at end of question). `realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])` won't work since the document root will not always be the same as the WordPress installation root. The installation could be in a subdirectory.

Comment: @CBroe I'm a flabbergasted that the solution might be as concise as what you've outlined. The code I'm modifying (as pasted in my question), is as the theme author originally wrote it. I'm presupposing that there ***has to be*** a legitimate reason why the author didn't use your obvious method but to be honest, I can't think of a single reason why not.

Comment: this can be done, but you are aware php will have to start with the root path and then search every folder for the file you are looking for? use `scandir()` and `file_exists()` or there is a iterator function for it in php5. But lookit, the standard for for extending code is that you follow conventions set by the original programmer, how about setting a filter for the filename and if someone wants to override, they can do so by add_filter?

Comment: @David Would searching every folder represent an extensive server load? Would you consider it overkill? Would the `add_filter` method not require connecting to the WordPress API which would require `wp-load.php` to be called in any case?

Comment: yes, how many folders are on your server. add filter would require both wp load and the code with the filter run. But why would you load files outside wp?

Comment: @David There's not an exceptional number of folders. Just the standard you'd expect for a regular WordPress install. The document, `style.php`, is a style-sheet that uses PHP to dynamically output options configured from the `wp-admin` front-end. Bear in mind that I'm modifying a theme that I didn't author. I understand that it's bad practice to have to call `wp-load.php`. I just don't like pointing out problems (in this case, to the author) unless I have the solutions.

Comment: hmm it sounds to me like you may be overcomplicating this. If you are modifying a theme, get_stylesheet_directory() + get_template_directory should resolve the url/path. If you are modifying the theme, create a child theme. I get that the theme folder is located outside wp, but for this to be working now, wordpress should be pointing to this folder already. So use of one of above functions will return the correct path for you or at least most of it (you may have to remove parts of the path to get the folder you want, but at least you know where the file is!)

Comment: @David By "modifying" I mean to say I'm simply modifying the path until the theme author gets around to a necessary updated release with a fix. I was hoping to find the necessary solution to expedite the author's release. It's not that the theme folder is located outside of WordPress, rather the document is a style.php file (contained in the theme root) that connects to WordPress API by calling wp-load.php. I can't use WordPress functions until this call is made. Here's a brief example of the code in action: http://pastebin.com/9GCW8ZMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to go three folders up, then using `../` three times will do.

---

I’d normally refrain from adding something this short (and rather trivial) as an answer – but since ClarusDignus reply to my previous comment suggests this sounds like it might be an appropriate and easy solution for his problem, why not make it an answer :-) Sometimes people just overlook the most obvious solution – and maybe this was such a case here with whoever wrote the code he’s dealing with now.

As long as the structure of the project itself is “static”, this method should work, no matter what directory level the project is placed at.

(The only circumstance where I could *possibly* see this *not* working is if PHP’s `include_path` was configured in a non-standard way – but this should be quite rare.)

Comment: Thanks cBroe. Though obvious and trivial in hindsight, I feel that in light of the comparative complexity of the alternative solutions being explored, this answer is important. Your answer reminds me of [this urban legend](http://www.snopes.com/business/genius/where.asp).

Comment: Actually, it's not that simple. For example, it's becoming a lot more common to have themes in "/home/somesite/public_html/wp-content/themes/" while WP is in its own directory, e.g. "/home/somesite/public_html/wp/".

Comment: @bobdye: That might be; I didn’t say this would work for every possible setup. Especially when one develops only components for a larger system, to be used by others as well, making use of pre-defined constants or variables that exists for such purposes would be preferable whenever possible.

Comment: @bobdye You're correct about subdirectory installation however refer to my question in a very literal sense and you'll find that CBroe has in fact answered what was asked. However, you're additionally correct in intuiting that this doesn't solve my overall problem based on the variability of file locations and file names however "solving my actual problem" and "answering the question that was asked" are two very different things. CBroe has achieved the latter though I acknowledge the greater value of what your answer attempts. Objectively, I have to accept this answer based on what I asked.

Comment: @ClarusDignus: If another answer provides more valuable insight or offers a better solution long-term, then feel free to accept that instead. (I would not claim that a one-liner that merely “states the obvious” deserves much credit anyway.) The answer that answers what was asked most literally doesn’t have to be the best (or even a good) one – if another answer delves deeper into the problem and caters to other factors that the initial question did not include, that’s fine by me :-)

Comment: @CBroe Therein lies the problem. Though in theory, bobdye is 100% correct and his answer indeed superior, in practice, I am unable to derive an understanding sufficient to produce a workable solution, particularly due the absence of a working code example. Prior to this comment, I've already appended a comment to bobdye's answer explaining this matter. Upon remedy, I'm happy to accept his answer. In the absence of remedy, your answer is the closest thing I have to a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you have provided I understand that the path will always end like `someFolder/themes/someTheme`.
You can just start looking from the end of the string and find the third or forth `/`, depending on the path having a trailing `/`.

```
$path = "/home/somesite/public_html/wp-content/themes/some-theme";
echo getBase($path); /* /home/somesite/public_html/ */

function getBase($path) {
    $i = substr($path,-1) == '/' ? 4 : 3;
    $end = strlen($path);
    $offset = 0;
    while($i > 0) {
        $end = strrpos($path, '/', -$offset);
        $offset = strlen($path) - $end+1;
        $i--;
    }
    return substr($path, 0, $end+1);
}
```

You can also use regex for this. I barely know any regex, so it might be a bad one, but you'll get an idea:

```
preg_match("/(.*)\/(.*)\/themes/", $path, $matches);
return $matches[1];
```

Comment: I can confirm the first solution works on my end but prior to selecting your answer, is CBroe's comment to my question correct?: _"If you just need to go three folders up, then using ../ three times will do."_ Are you aware of any downside to CBroe's suggestion or is actually that simple?

Comment: Yes, it is that easy. However, this will not work if `some-theme` is a file. I dont know wordpress..

Comment: `some-theme` is the folder containing the document that your code is being added to. The `_FILE_` of `dirname( __FILE__ );`  is the file that the `/home/somesite/public_html/wp-content/themes/some-theme/style.php` path leads to. Nonetheless, thanks for your time and the sleek function.

Comment: Well, then you can just add `../` three times as suggested. Poor inodes thinking they do a job.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Since this is, from what you say, a WordPress site, you can't get what you're looking for without involving WordPress.

- As you say, the content directory can be called anything. But it can also be located anywhere. All you need to do it define the location was WP_CONTENT_DIR in wp-config.php.
- wp-load.php can also be anywhere, and it's location does not necessarily relate to the location of the content directory. The location of the WordPress directory, which contains wp-load.php, is defined in a variable ABSPATH in wp-config.php.

The location of the WordPress directory, and thus the location of wp-load.php, would need to be found by:

- Configuration for your program (don't know if this is practical for you)
- In the index.php of the WordPress root. Index needs to load wp-blog-header.php from there.

It is also in the WordPress database, but since the tables there can have a configurable prefix it's hard to definitively get it from there.

Comment: Understood but doesn't the same problem transpire with the location of wp-config.php? I know it can definitely be moved up one directory though I'm uncertain of whatever locations it might be allowed to reside.

Comment: If you look in wp-load.php, you will see that it looks for "wp-config.php" first in ABSPATH and then in dirname(ABSPATH). If it doesn't find it in one of those, then it routes to the setup page. I forgot that until you mentioned it, and adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry but my mind is looping in a chicken/egg scenario. I understand that you're saying to include wp-config to allow the use of ABSPATH to locate wp-load but with regards to your last comment, I don't understand how prior to this, I'm expected to use wp-load to locate wp-config (since I'm using wp-config to locate wp-load). It seems like an impossible loop where I'm using one to find the other. Am I misunderstanding your explanation? I seem to be having difficulty visualising the process.

Comment: You're right, I did write it so that it was looping. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Based on my circumstances your concern about configured table prefix is valid. I don't know what "Configuration for your program" is referring to. Does this refer to where I originally installed WordPress, wp-admin settings or a specific file? I don't see anything in index.php that suggests how to define the necessary path and overall, I'm unable to derive your conclusion or recommended action from your edited answer.

Comment: What I meant about configuration was, since this is in a WordPress environment, is it possible to ask the user to tell you where the WP directory is? As far as index.php, it has to load "wp-blog-header.php" from the WP directory. Although this option is not 100% guaranteed (and thus less desirable), if you look at the line with "wp-blog-header.php" on it, you can almost always determine where it is (and therefore where wp-load.php is).

Comment: Sorry bobdye, each answer seems to beget a new question. Rather than contriving this thread with further abstract theory and misunderstandings on my part, if you can possibly provide some working example code, I'd be happy to select this as the correct answer.